# NSTableView with plist file

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, nstableview, nswindowcontroller

I am very new to mac app development. so just doing some practical exercise.

I want to create a tableview which display data from my plist file.
I have one windowcontroller class and window controller.xib file.
I drag and drop NSTableView to the .xib file.
and using this code to load plist file

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"tenth" ofType:@"plist"];
    file = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

}
```

Now what should i do for displaying rows in my tableview??
Which method i have to use? and how??

like in IOS development we are using

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSArray *temp = [file objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll want to represent a property list with an NSTableView. On OS X trees are usually represented with an NSOutlineView. Property list files are not flat structures and flattening them will cause problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html) with an `NSArrayController` or [implement the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html).

Recommended reading: [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html).