# How I can add NSString to NSTableView in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSTableView with plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385792/nstableview-with-plist-file)

I'm new in using UI Cocoa controls. I need to browse directory, and display it in NSTAbleView. It shoud have 3 columns, one for image. How can I add data or NSString to NSTableView? I need basic and easiest idea. Or any tutorial that simply adds something to NSTableView. Thanks. I forgot to tell I am using Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own object that stores the file names in the directory, implements the data source protocol to return them, and hook that up to the table view using `-setDataSource:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is best to use for storing file names, NSDictionary ?

Comment: Probably NSArray. `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third", nil]`

Answer (score 0):

Better follow MVC model. Have a class which contains only the data needed for the tableView, one for creating the View(tableView and custom cell) and a controller which mediates between your model and Views.
Or
You can have a custom tableViewCell which has your desired elements. After creating the customed tableViewCell, add its View to the tableView. And you are done.